# Is there any way to let users begin downloading a file before it's finished uploading?

Tags: uploading, file-sharing, download

Anyone have any ideas on how to implement this?..  I am building a file sharing site and I want to allow users to begin downloading files before there even finished uploading.  Is this possible?

Comment: sounds a lot like consuming half of a half baked cake... don't think it will be possible

Comment: Are you planning on using an existing protocol for file transfer, or are you rolling your own?

Comment: This has to be possible; all P2P-like programs do this (ie. in BitTorrent, you can seed before you are done downloading). However, depending on what programming language you are using, you might have to do a bit of work (by default, PHP sticks the file into `/tmp` and doesn't move it until after it is done uploading). Therefore, you might have to do a bit of research on whether this would work with the HTTP protocol (assuming that's what you're using) and the programming language you're using on the server.

Comment: I realize that torrents don't actually allow you to say if your downloading a video begin watching before it's done downloading.  Do you think there would be anyway to implement this aswell?

Comment: Depending on the file format of the video, you could begin to stream the video, in which case it doesn't need the entire video to begin playing. (As an example, YouTube and all other video-streaming sites do this - you don't need to wait for the entire video to load before it starts playing.) Also, you could try using a video-streaming protocol like [rtmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) (which works well with Flash, but not much else).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any standard protocol like FTP or HTTP support this, but maybe you could think about integrating a peer-to-peer, BitTorrent-like sharing method.

Your server would just act as another peer until the file is uploaded to the server completely, after which the server acts like any other file server.

EDIT: (since I can't comment on the question yet, I'll comment here) Actually, you can watch videos while BitTorrent is still downloading it. The µTorrent client even allows this by default. It prioritizes the first pieces of a file so you can watch the first pieces until one is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you can access a partial file (as least on Unix systems) as if it were any other file, however I'd really not recommending using such an approach unless this is some form of Torrent like solution that will just "share" the complete chunks and even then I'd have reservations.

For example, how would you handle the situation where the upload of the "source" file fails shortly before completion?